# Connection issues after turning off embedded LDAP

Tags: wso2, openldap, wso2-identity-server

When disabling embedded-LDAP in my Identity Server install, I receive the following startup errors:

> [2017-10-09 14:12:03,955] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LDAPConnectionContext} -  Error
>   obtaining connection. [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr:
>   DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1]
>   javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308:
>   LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data
>   52e, v1db1]
>
> Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Cannot create
>   connection to LDAP server. Error message Error obtaining connection.
>   [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment:
>   AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1]

Specs are: IS v5.3.0 on Ubuntu Xenial. Part of the Identity Server documentation on configuring a read-only LDAP user store specifies [disabling Embedded LDAP](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+a+Read-only+LDAP+User+Store)

I initially configured read-only LDAP settings in my user-mgt.xml file and that worked without issue, however disabling embedded-LDAP is now causing startup LDAP connection issues and I can't figure out why. I searched this particular error message and could not find anything related.

Comment: [49  data 52e](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP_INVALID_CREDENTIALS) Returns when username is valid but password/credential is invalid. Most likely you have some none printable character in your password, when you copied from UI to XML.

Comment: Ruwan, appreciate it. I confirmed this behavior when the user account locked out unexpectedly. It appears the password needs to be in a specific format for WSO2 to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Password doesn't support certain characters.