# WSO2 Identity Server 5.3.0 CipherTool Bug

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Identity server 5.3.0. Recently patched. I've replaced the default keystore and keys with my own. Utilizing the ciphertool to remove plain text passwords from various config files. I've successfully replaced the database password inside of repository/conf/datasources files using the ciphertool. Restarted the IS successfully. Was moving on to the keystore values inside of the carbon.xml file and I keep getting the following error:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-10-16 21:39:44,322] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Error while pdating wso2carbon-sts in STSDeploymentInterceptor 
java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:780)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
```

...

```
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:778)
    ... 53 more
```

I've confirmed the password is correct. I even re-replaced the ciphertool reference inside of carbon.xml with the clear text value and restart successfully, again. My only guess at this point is that ciphertool is not handling special characters correctly. My pass has an ampersand (@). Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:** Went through the effort of recreating a brand new key store and key with a simple password... no special characters. Same results. After running ciphertool.bat -Dconfigure my carbon.xml entries looks good (see below). Which indicates the Xpath in cipher-tool.properties is correct. And I've triple checked the password in cipher-text.properties.

```
<KeyStore>
    <!-- Keystore file location-->
    <Location>${carbon.home}/repository/resources/security/KeyStore.jks</Location>
    <!-- Keystore type (JKS/PKCS12 etc.)-->
    <Type>JKS</Type>
    <!-- Keystore password-->
    <Password svns:secretAlias="Conf.Carbon.KeyStore.Password">password</Password>
    <!-- Private Key alias-->
    <KeyAlias>QaCert</KeyAlias>
    <!-- Private Key password-->
    <KeyPassword svns:secretAlias="Conf.Carbon.KeyPassword">password</KeyPassword>
</KeyStore>
```

Answer (score 0):

John, I would submit this bug to WSO2's [GitHub](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues) or [JIRA instance](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY):

On a side note, I noticed WSO2's use of encrypted passwords has an issue with special characters. This could be a general problem if WSO2 IS is using CipherTool to automatically encrypt passwords in the WebUI. See my comment at the bottom of this post:

[Connection issues after turning off embedded LDAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46652727/connection-issues-after-turning-off-embedded-ldap)